# Make bootable USB drive on Mac

Tags: usb, buildroot, syslinux

I've tried to make a bootable USB drive — using Syslinux & Buildroot — on my Macbook Air.

When I boot up I get something like this error.

```
"Non-system disk, press any key to restart"
```

Does that mean that Syslinux has not even started, and hence that there is some problem with formatting, or with my dd-command? Can an error in syslinux.cfg cause this error?

This is my command history.

```
  477  mkdir BootableUSB
  478  cd BootableUSB/
  479  curl -L -O http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-5.00.zip
  480  unzip syslinux-5.00.zip -d syslinux-5.00
  481  cd syslinux-5.00/mbr/
  :
  486  diskutil list
  487  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
  488  sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2
  489  man fdisk
  490  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
  491  sudo dd conv=notrunc bs=440 count=1 if=mbr.bin of=/dev/disk2
  492  diskutil list
  493  ls 
  494  cp syslinux.cfg /Volumes/FREDRIK\ USB/
  495  emacs syslinux.cfg 
  496  pwd
  497  emacs syslinux.cfg 
  498  cp syslinux.cfg /Volumes/FREDRIK\ USB/
  499  diskutil list
  500  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
  501  history
```

And inside the disk command (489):

```
Fredriks-Air:mbr eternity$ sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2
Password:
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1> print
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 3781/255/63 [60751872 sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         2 -   60751870] Win95 FAT-32
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
fdisk: 1> f 1
Partition 1 marked active.
fdisk:*1> write
Writing MBR at offset 0.
fdisk: 1> 
fdisk: 1> print
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 3781/255/63 [60751872 sectors]
Offset: 0   Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
*1: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         2 -   60751870] Win95 FAT-32
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
fdisk: 1> exit
```

And finally my syslinux.cfg:

```
cat syslinux.cfg
DEFAULT linux
#APPEND initrd=rootfs.gz root=/dev/ram0
TIMEOUT 10
```